# Use a WebView to run JavaScript

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to use a simple WebView to fetch the content of a website, which includes JavaScript. I don't want to really show the WebView, I only want to get the source code of the site. The view where I will load the request from, is not in the window hierarchy. The method is getting called from another view. 
Something like this:

MainView.m:

```
 [[HelperView alloc]LoadWebview];
```

HelperView.m:

```
-(void)LoadWebview {

        webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
        [webView setDelegate:self];
        [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]]; 
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Is it possible to use the delegate methods from this WebView in a view, which is not in the window hierarchy, or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to get the source code then try this:

```
-(void)loadWebview{
//Create an NSURL object
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourWebsiteHere.com"];

//Create a string to hold the source code
NSString *sourceCode= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];

//Do what you want with the source code here!

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it's not that easy because of the Javascript. The Webview finished loading before the JS loaded all the content.